# How to do a query in Realm that checks attributes for related objects?

Tags: swift, realm

```
class Question: Object {
    var answers = List<Answer>()

}

class Answer: Object {

    dynamic var date: NSDate? = nil
    dynamic var question: Question!
    dynamic var correct = false

}
```

I have a database filled with `Questions`. When a user answers a question, an Answer object is created, with todays date and if the answer was correct. 
With Realm, is it possible to do a query that finds the question in the database with the fewest number of correct answers?

I tried with

```
realm.objects(Question).filter("answers.@count == @min AND answers.correct == true")
```

but aggregate functions can't be combined with other aggregate functions, seems the `@count` and `@min` cant be used in the same query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no easy way to query for results what you want to get.

The simple solution is adding `count` property for correct answers to `Question` object.

```
class Question: Object {
    let answers = List<Answer>()
    dynamic var correctAnswerCount = 0
}
```

Then you can query a question that has the fewest number of correct answers.

```
let fewest = realm
    .objects(Question)
    .sorted("correctAnswerCount", ascending: true).first
```